# FLV's not being served by web server (302 response)

Tags: iis-6, flv

I have a web app. IIS 6. .NET 3.5.
I have 2 websites on the web server. One of which is already correctly serving FLVs. The newer one is not.

I have added the MIME type information to the HTTP Headers in the website properties ['.flv', 'video/x-flv'] (as FLV is not an extension IIS recognises by default).

When I goto the URL, Firefox goes black and displays "Waiting for video". It stays like this. I have checked the logs that IIS writes to, and I have found the GET request, and the HTTP status associated with it, which is 302. This is a "Moved Temporarily" status code. I don't understand why it would be throwing this. All other content on this site (currently consisting of webpages and images) is returned fine.

I have tried the same video in the older site, and just directing FF to the URL, it runs correctly.

Any help as to why I can't do this would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Unless you are mapping *.flv to the ASP.NET process, this has nothing to do with ASP.NET.  Removed tag.

Comment: What did you set for the MIME Type in IIS?  My instance of IIS7 uses "video/x-flv", just FYI.

Comment: Ah, OK. I'm not mapping it to the ASP.NET process. 
I also set the MIME to video/x-flv